# C# Value Type Lists

Tags: c#, list, collections, value-type

I'm a bit confused.  Structs are more or less value types that get constructed on the stack and therefore have a straightforward lifetime.

When building a list with a struct, you cannot modify them directly because the returned value is a copy, and won't actually modify the item stored in the list.

My confusion comes here:  Why can I not directly change a struct item in a list, but I can directly access and modify the base value types (int, float, etc...)?

This works:

```
 List<int> foobar1 = new List<int>();
 foobar1.Add(1);
 foobar1[0] = 2;
```

This Doesn't:

```
public struct foo
{
    public int bar;
}

...         

List<foo> foobar2 = new List<foo>();
foobar2.Add(new foo());
foobar2[0].bar = 2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are fundamentally different, and not just because someone decided that it is, let me explain.

The first piece of code replaces wholesale the `int` value in the 0th element position in the list. It doesn't matter which `int` value is there, afterwards the list contains the `int` value `2` in the 0th position.

The second piece of code, however, is attempting to replace *parts* of the struct. Yes, I know, the struct only has one field but the compiler makes no such distinction. You're effectively modifying a copy of the struct retrieved from the list. This is not allowed.

So the first piece of code just stuffs a new value type into the list, the second piece of code tries to modify the value type from the list, which is a copy.

So, can you change the second piece of code to be like the first, ie. replace the element in the list completely?

Sure:

```
var temp = foobar[0];
temp.bar = 2;
foobar2[0] = temp; // no longer modifies the copy, but replaces the element
```

Basically, this right here:

```
foobar2[0].bar = 2;
          ^    ^
          |    |
```

is the problem.

Comment: makes a lot more sense, so if I were to modify i'd have to replace it with a whole new foo

Comment: You could read the copy, modify the copy locally (in a local variable) and then stuff the modified copy back into the list, you're just not allowed to do all of that in one statement.

Comment: Well. `foobar[0] = new foo { bar = foobar[0].bar + 2 };` but thats just ugly.